# How to retrieve the full dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a dictionary in Class A and would like to return the entire list (Key, Value) in class B. Are there any suggestions on how can I do this? I have tried a number of things from the internet but nothing seems to be working. I am trying to write a method in class A to retrieve the entire dictionary.

```cs
public class_A
{
  public static Dictionary<string, string> Dict_1 = new Dictionary();
  public add_dict(string name, string add)
  {
     Dict_1.Add(name, add);
  }

  public dict return_dictionary()
  {
    return (Dict_1); // I want to have a proper code to return this dictionary.
  }
}
```

Comment: I think some code would help. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: The question doesn't have any details that could help us answering it.

Comment: Your best bet to get quality answers is learning how to ask, first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this dictionary is a private member in your class. You can access this Dictionary by an encapuslated method.

```
public class A
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> _items { set;get;}
    public Dictionary<string, int> GetItems()
    {
        return _items 
    }
}
```

and in class B, Create an object and access it

```
A objA = new A();
Dictionary<string, int> thatItems=objA.GetItems();
```

**EDIT : As per the edit in the question**
You have some propblems in your code.

You can not write a class like this `public class_A`. It should be `public class A`

Your Dictionary declaration should be like this

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> Dict_1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Your add_dict method needs a return type. ( I am just adding void, you can have a bool or whatever you wish)

```
public void add_dict(string name, string add)
{
    Dict_1.Add(name, add);
}
```

Your method return type should be `Dictionary<string, string>`. They you are good.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> return_dictionary()
{
    return Dict_1;
}
```

But look into your code, Your `Dict_1`  property is a public property. So you another class dont even need your return_dictionary method to get the data. It can simply access the data like

```
A objA = new A();
Dictionary<string, string> stolenData = objA.Dict_1;
```

So Encapsulation concept is broken !

Better you should keep your member as private like this. I just changed your method names and variable names to follow some coding/naming conventions for better readability.

```
public class A
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public void Add_dict(string name, string add)
    {
        _dict.Add(name, add);
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Return_dictionary()
    {
        return _dict; 
    }
}
```

This is a good reading to understand Encapsulation http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson19.aspx